# Xorg crash after `ACPI group/action undefined: jack/videoout / VIDEOOUT`

Tags: linux, x11, nvidia, acpi

Since the last couple of days, Xorg crashes about once a day, completely at random. When it crashes, my monitors turn black and a couple seconds afterwards LightDM's login manager pops up.

I'm on Arch `5.15.2`, bspwm, nvidia proprietary driver version `495.44-9`. Both the kernel and nvidia driver were recently updated, so they might be the cause.
My system is a Lenovo Legion 5 Pro with `Ryzen 7 5800H`, `RTX 3070 Mobile` and `16GB RAM`. I'm using two external monitors: one connected to HDMI, one to a USB-C output.

Strangely, two of the crashes happened when watching videos on reddit, both when something very loud and high-pitched suddenly happened. The crash happens either right when the loud noise happens, or right when I quickly lower my volume using my mouse buttons. I'm always using headphones, connected to the 3.5mm port (Beyerdynamic DT 770 Pro 80 Ohm).
Other crashes seem to be random. I haven't had any crashes happen when the monitors weren't plugged in, but I haven't used my laptop that way much lately.

Looking at `journalctl`, the crash always happen right after these ACPI jack/videoout and jack/lineout lines:

```
Nov 20 11:16:00 zjeffer root[251860]: ACPI group/action undefined: jack/lineout / LINEOUT
Nov 20 11:16:00 zjeffer root[251862]: ACPI group/action undefined: jack/videoout / VIDEOOUT
Nov 20 11:16:01 zjeffer acpid[562]: client 607[0:0] has disconnected
Nov 20 11:16:01 zjeffer acpid[562]: client 607[0:0] has disconnected
Nov 20 11:16:01 zjeffer root[251995]: ACPI group/action undefined: jack/lineout / LINEOUT
Nov 20 11:16:01 zjeffer root[251997]: ACPI group/action undefined: jack/videoout / VIDEOOUT
Nov 20 11:16:01 zjeffer systemd[1]: Created slice Slice /system/systemd-coredump.
Nov 20 11:16:01 zjeffer systemd[1]: Started Process Core Dump (PID 251993/UID 0).
Nov 20 11:16:01 zjeffer systemd-coredump[252000]: [?] Process 607 (Xorg) of user 0 dumped core.
                                                  
                                                  Found module linux-vdso.so.1 with build-id: 86aa67c5d299799c7345d04bd8a2c511eeea459e
                                                  Found module libffi.so.8 with build-id: f90d8b734f6de9b25faedb8cbfab7054dafc0a42
                                                  Found module libgobject-2.0.so.0 with build-id: 3e451709a0a5772b9550d3a4c28dcb37a87028fa
                                                  Found module libgudev-1.0.so.0 with build-id: a9f734ea9206d637d5aacfbd86298c91cdc1a33a
                                                  Found module libwacom.so.2 with build-id: 1d9b89a6d39be5568d5f44888b8a74f46a30c152
                                                  Found module libevdev.so.2 with build-id: b62ae69f839f1b6b06ef2c1df19f25ff09b0d824
                                                  Found module libmtdev.so.1 with build-id: 0cea2a842ae9a0ef02a08477076caab0e5ac5e42
                                                  Found module libinput.so.10 with build-id: 77f3eca5dddc8cac29b71bc5041a79ce57fceb56
                                                  Found module libinput_drv.so with build-id: d9f69f11259485316bd206e67e34dd23bbede5cc
                                                  Found module libnvidia-glcore.so.495.44 with build-id: d634ab77fa6c8b0b33973dff2606227df42dd0ec
                                                  Found module libnvidia-tls.so.495.44 with build-id: 744df1115e69d5caab88537c0d3983a3783cec8a
                                                  Found module libglxserver_nvidia.so with build-id: 02da342fa6a34200029b4c60a3f2cd23ac6b2ba3
                                                  Found module libwfb.so with build-id: 06de5be0f21630de392a79771f5d81ac62a0cf9f
                                                  Found module nvidia_drv.so with build-id: 9fa1f2f377b54e8cdeb3bc6224a79ffa8794b223
                                                  Found module libxcb.so.1 with build-id: 0d1ef11740a5daad2ee331e812a51aa6574af222
                                                  Found module libX11.so.6 with build-id: e9192497aa39fab51358826d1a1b5fb77edc5081
                                                  Found module libGLX.so.0 with build-id: 0f40ceaa036edc65147e9559b94e0219472493fc
                                                  Found module libGLdispatch.so.0 with build-id: 195b34c1bb271f3b1162c897cfbcfb859e656b93
                                                  Found module libGL.so.1 with build-id: 8b3028bab286029945569a0dfcf695f0f61d9c3b
                                                  Found module libglx.so with build-id: a506bc474051e9b92e7c4cbc17874e18c48ed1f0
                                                  Found module libgcc_s.so.1 with build-id: 7f8508bb914546ada778809b64b99d234337d835
                                                  Found module libpcre.so.1 with build-id: 845483dd0acba86de9f0313102bebbaf3ce52767
                                                  Found module libbrotlicommon.so.1 with build-id: f68934f94312f770550ebc6c5acfd6359b098b07
                                                  Found module libglib-2.0.so.0 with build-id: d4aa102e545015a506c3ee06398676b70f65bcbc
                                                  Found module libgraphite2.so.3 with build-id: 47761dc11e553f519cde97ed9ee985be12ccdae2
                                                  Found module libresolv.so.2 with build-id: c915c72668282861a813f7ea3c0780f37b681dc0
                                                  Found module libkeyutils.so.1 with build-id: ac405ddd17be10ce538da3211415ee50c8f8df79
                                                  Found module libkrb5support.so.0 with build-id: adf65240a4d2aba772d7a0772b4d015469934113
                                                  Found module libcom_err.so.2 with build-id: eb61ef71c8b97846db759fb89a115405cff6dd30
                                                  Found module libk5crypto.so.3 with build-id: eb8220b8f36675aac769450be4cb6bb7f97ec38a
                                                  Found module libkrb5.so.3 with build-id: 72d26767c5cb1097db75a5f5bff88860233c902b
                                                  Found module libgpg-error.so.0 with build-id: 3801187d42c4955bd93c605451430cdf1b164e63
                                                  Found module libbrotlidec.so.1 with build-id: f871e6f204ab8d48099915126ba01be989a8000f
                                                  Found module libharfbuzz.so.0 with build-id: f3507938a0d15efd3c81f0f9f1dd98cfdaf2144f
                                                  Found module libpng16.so.16 with build-id: 2dc0bce07f199bf983c07a05fb95a6f4af83a9b3
                                                  Found module libbz2.so.1.0 with build-id: 919597c477c9b2cb9cdbb7745ed6494ac0e6da60
                                                  Found module libgssapi_krb5.so.2 with build-id: e6e098ad51ce7bdd3dbe902d7b0f69a90f8a9e08
                                                  Found module libgcrypt.so.20 with build-id: db45f5d5e0f7af1e77324fea1885f974619ad268
                                                  Found module libcap.so.2 with build-id: f028e24efdfb362a37fa8dd280c3894b007f88b1
                                                  Found module liblz4.so.1 with build-id: e63600ab23b2f6997f42fac2fa56e1f02ce159a1
                                                  Found module libzstd.so.1 with build-id: 4b10444c1560ebc574af4d5f488b7408b22d450e
                                                  Found module liblzma.so.5 with build-id: 8b615460aa230708c5183f16bede67aa0437d95e
                                                  Found module librt.so.1 with build-id: 75484da2d6f1515189eefa076e0a40328834cd16
                                                  Found module libfreetype.so.6 with build-id: 65e7f4a1e5557b0ceeaa433e5356f857fe9c669b
                                                  Found module libfontenc.so.1 with build-id: 5a11f1fb8c3f2714be9eb6697318f20e301e1d2f
                                                  Found module libz.so.1 with build-id: 81bf6e728a6d6f5b105b0f8b25f6c614ce10452a
                                                  Found module ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with build-id: 040cc3dd10461562f177df39e3be2f3704258c3c
                                                  Found module libc.so.6 with build-id: 4b406737057708c0e4c642345a703c47a61c73dc
                                                  Found module libxcvt.so.0 with build-id: 30bad674c8227152bb709556a3657d0258554309
                                                  Found module libpthread.so.0 with build-id: 07c8f95b4f3251d08550217ad8a1f31066229996
                                                  Found module libtirpc.so.3 with build-id: 5bef2adfdee3df283f593b3e2d37b6dac405256a
                                                  Found module libdrm.so.2 with build-id: 8585630908d716a9ebf17abe665324984d15aa13
                                                  Found module libudev.so.1 with build-id: 9070ad2429e5355a96e0327226532a60f5abcb6f
                                                  Found module libdbus-1.so.3 with build-id: 74f2ab9c60512f3a93c932c3f627564d42e0b11e
                                                  Found module libsystemd.so.0 with build-id: 4173ca7f3b7338e7e0b8399eb75d6a7320c5f7f5
                                                  Found module libxshmfence.so.1 with build-id: 8876d9ccf620858795724ca24b9e567585a77cec
                                                  Found module libXfont2.so.2 with build-id: 154202dd7ddb86f6ae4d3bc762dfd8570b86882a
                                                  Found module libXdmcp.so.6 with build-id: 8ca0792d23c8b8b4c0864297512349292bea5955
                                                  Found module libXau.so.6 with build-id: 1c67764663e07bec24d8951e5fd93f4d165979ff
                                                  Found module libnettle.so.8 with build-id: 9a878e513c02007598fcf1e2e286c2203f13536e
                                                  Found module libpciaccess.so.0 with build-id: 9dd24e76ebc38465541313b36446ffb4af842c12
                                                  Found module libdl.so.2 with build-id: 5abc547e7b0949f89f3c0e21ab0c8331a7440a8a
                                                  Found module libm.so.6 with build-id: 2b8fd1f869ecab4e0b55e92f2f151897f6818acf
                                                  Found module libpixman-1.so.0 with build-id: 341f793dcada3a48a306a793d265a517e3f2e7d6
                                                  Found module Xorg with build-id: 18a012a3f10bafde1b37c70c13fd821a3eccaa89
                                                  Stack trace of thread 607:
                                                  #0  0x00007f65fae93d22 raise (libc.so.6 + 0x3cd22)
                                                  #1  0x00007f65fae7d862 abort (libc.so.6 + 0x26862)
                                                  #2  0x0000558fcd52166a OsAbort (Xorg + 0x14f66a)
                                                  #3  0x0000558fcd523171 FatalError (Xorg + 0x151171)
                                                  #4  0x0000558fcd528a76 n/a (Xorg + 0x156a76)
                                                  #5  0x00007f65fb03b870 __restore_rt (libpthread.so.0 + 0x13870)
                                                  #6  0x0000558fcd457ecd n/a (Xorg + 0x85ecd)
                                                  #7  0x0000558fcd4db159 n/a (Xorg + 0x109159)
                                                  #8  0x0000558fcd5146f4 XkbHandleActions (Xorg + 0x1426f4)
                                                  #9  0x0000558fcd5a961e n/a (Xorg + 0x1d761e)
                                                  #10 0x0000558fcd502dfa n/a (Xorg + 0x130dfa)
                                                  #11 0x0000558fcd51c220 n/a (Xorg + 0x14a220)
                                                  #12 0x0000558fcd51c532 WaitForSomething (Xorg + 0x14a532)
                                                  #13 0x0000558fcd40c5ab n/a (Xorg + 0x3a5ab)
                                                  #14 0x00007f65fae7eb25 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6 + 0x27b25)
                                                  #15 0x0000558fcd40d4ce _start (Xorg + 0x3b4ce)
                                                  
                                                  Stack trace of thread 764:
                                                  #0  0x00007f65fb03a600 __lll_lock_wait (libpthread.so.0 + 0x12600)
                                                  #1  0x00007f65fb033580 __pthread_mutex_lock (libpthread.so.0 + 0xb580)
                                                  #2  0x0000558fcd516d11 n/a (Xorg + 0x144d11)
                                                  #3  0x0000558fcd5212b1 n/a (Xorg + 0x14f2b1)
                                                  #4  0x0000558fcd51d411 n/a (Xorg + 0x14b411)
                                                  #5  0x00007f65fb031259 start_thread (libpthread.so.0 + 0x9259)
                                                  #6  0x00007f65faf555e3 __clone (libc.so.6 + 0xfe5e3)
```

Full output of `journalctl -b`: https://pastebin.com/aqevKaSV

These ACPI videoout and lineout lines seem to pop up quite often, but they don't always cause a crash. I don't think I've ever seen them before until this week, and I've had this laptop since July.

- What is the meaning of the `jack/lineout` and `jack/videoout` ACPI errors? I get that they are not defined in `/etc/acpi/handler.sh`, but what causes them?
- Because some of the crashes happened when something very loud happens, could the issue be related to sudden large power draws? Stresstesting seems to work fine, though.
- Looking at the Xorg stacktrace, the crash seems to happen after calling the `__restore_rt` function. What does this signify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a bug report on the Arch Linux bugtracker: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/72799

It seems to be fixed now.